# Type shown as parameter value with Url.Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dictionary

With this code:

```
var stocks = new Dictionary<string, string>() {{"MSFT", "Microsoft Corporation"}, {"AAPL", "Apple, Inc."}};
<a href="@Url.Action("Test", new {stocks})">Test Item</a>
```

the URL that gets created is:

```
http://localhost:58930/d/m/5b1ab3a0-4bb3-467a-93fe-08eb16e2bb8d/Center/Test?stocks=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.String%5D
```

Which displays the type instead of the data.  Why is this?  How do I pass the data?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `Dictionary<T, U>` doesn't override ToString(). Anonymous objects created this way, `var stocks = new { MSFT = "Microsoft Corporation", AAPL = "Apple, Inc." };`, do. The anonymous object produces { MSFT = Microsoft Corporation, AAPL = Apple, Inc. } as its output when ToString() is called, which Action parses to create parameters. I believe that you should also be able to use a `System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary` that's created like this, `RouteValueDictionary stocks = new RouteValueDictionary { { "MSFT ", "Microsoft Corporation" }, { "AAPL", "Apple, Inc." } };`.

Comment: That gives me this URL: 
http://localhost:58930/d/m/5b1ab3a0-4bb3-467a-93fe-08eb16e2bb8d/Center/Test?stocks=System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary
which does not pass the values either.

Comment: Are you doing `new { stocks }` still or feeding it just `stocks`? With the `RouteValueDictionary`, you shouldn't need the `new` in your `Url.Action` call.

Comment: Also, if this still doesn't provide the URL you're looking for, please provide a sample of what you'd like the actual URL to look like.

Answer (score 0):

UrlHelper.Action takes an anonymous object that is converted internally to a `RouteValueDictionary`:

```
Url.Action("Test", new { "MSFT" = "Microsoft Corporation", "APPL" = "Apple, Inc." })
```

Or directly a `RouteValueDictionary`:

```
Url.Action("Test", new RouteValueDictionary() {{}})
```

And it matches the dictionary keys against the action parameters. If they match, the value is added to the query string (or the route path, depending on the Url routing rules).

So, if your action does not have parameters called MSFT or APPL, the routing will not work. You'll need to [serialize the dictionary](http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-dictionary-string) (or any other way of passing the data as a string)  and pass it as an encoded string (with `HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode`) to the `UrlHelper`:

```
Url.Action("Test", new { "stocks", serializedDictionary });
```

Then in the action you'll have to extract the data again from the serialized dictionary.